# Связь vue.js и php с помощью ajax

Tags: php, vue.js

Здраствуйте, хотел связать файл vue.js и php, но возникли проблемы. Или я прописываю неправильный url, или я что-то не понимаю в ajax. Ниже мой проект(файл, с которым я хочу связать vue - это Server.php). Я пробовал с axios, но всегда выдает 404 ошибку, хотя прописываю вроде правильный путь к php файлу

[image: Файлы проекта]

Код vue.js:

```
mounted(){
   axios.post('/src/Server.php').then((res) => console.log(res));
},
```

Код Server.php:

```
<?php

echo "Hello world";
```

Comment: Идеальная связка `PHP` + `Vue` это [`Laravel`](https://laravel.com/).

Comment: Как вы запускаете php? Можно ли получить доступ к url /src/Server.php например в браузере. Убедитесь что она работает напрямую, а потому уже можно тестировать во Vue